# Issues with MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

my procedure just doesn't get created... gives an error

```
[SQL]CREATE DEFINER = `root``%` PROCEDURE `sp_getemployee`(IN  _ulbid    INT , IN  _designationid    INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE queryString VARCHAR(500);
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

The SP is something like this.

```
    CREATE DEFINER = `root``%` PROCEDURE `sp_getemployee`(IN  _ulbid    INT , IN  _designationid    INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE queryString VARCHAR(500);

SET queryString = CONCAT('select 
empid,empnumber,designationid,namee,namer,mobileno,isactive from employee where ulbid= ', _ulbid);

IF _designationid != 0 THEN 

  SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString , ' and designationid= ', _designationid);

END IF;

PREPARE stmt FROM queryString;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Absolutely no idea where i am going wrong, can someone please figure it out for me

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I got `5.7.14-google-log` when i did `SELECT @@VERSION`